# Monitoring a directory for subdirectory complete creation and then launching another process, c++

Tags: c++, winapi

So I have an idea that I would like to implement and it's as follows:

1. Monitor a specific directory.
2. once a sub-directory is not only created but completed (i.e. a folder that's being downloaded or copied has just completed) the code calls a procedure or a scheme to compress the folder.

I have a sort of an idea of implementing this using ReadDirectoryChangesW. However my question is how to wait for changes, but when a change happens, it waits for its completeness. The second question would be how to identify the subfolder that's completed so I can call the compression scheme and supply it as an argument.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know beforehand what the completed folder is supposed to look like (which files/subfolders it should contain)? Because if you don't you will be out of luck. The complex operations you describe are implemented as a succession of simple file changes and it is impossible to detect whether any of those is the 'last' in a chain of changes.

Comment: You may have to start a timer when a change is detected, reset the timer each time a new change is detected, and then do the compression when the timer elapses once the folder activity has become idle. Unfortunately, `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` does not tell you WHAT changed exactly, so you will have to either scan the directory yourself to find out, or use `SHChangeNotifyRegister()` to get that kind of information.

Comment: What you're trying to do is in general not possible. Unless the application that performs the download has a way of telling you that a download finished, there is nothing built into the system that will give you that information. The solutions proposed in the comments above will not work reliably.

Comment: What if first I look for the creation of a subdirectory. When that happens the compression scheme will constantly check the subdirectory until no change happens. After that the compression begins. Is that possible?

Comment: That's possible, but not reliable. How long are you going to wait? 5 seconds? A day maybe? You need a specific event from the application (download has completed). If the application doesn't offer this event there's no way to implement a reliable solution.

Comment: You could perhaps check for open handles to that directory, but that too isn't bulletproof. However, if there _is_ an open handle, you should definitely not try to work on it.

Comment: Is this possible through using FileSystemWatcher class not in C# but in C++ ?

Comment: @user2844838: There's no such class in C++; you'd have to write one yourself (the WinAPI is not a class)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's labelled "winapi", just set the NTFS compression attribute on the subdirectory as soon as you see it. Any new files in that directory will be automatically compressed as they're created.

Comment: What if I want to compress the subdirectory altogether, not individual files alone. Will what you suggested be sufficient?

Comment: @user2844838: I'm not even sure what that means. Do you mean Unix style `tar` ? NTFS already stores small files physically inside the directory clusters.